# Append two strings

Tags: smalltalk, squeak

I'm trying to append two string to each other in squeak(version 4.5) and there is no success.
For example(what i wish to do):

```
str1:='hello '.
str2:='world'.
appendStr:= str1 + str2.
```

There is a way to do that in squeak?
(note: the + operator is not necessary- just example)

Thanks a lot,
Nisan.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is possible, you need to use the `#,`  (comma) message like this:

```
| string1 string2 complete |
string1 := 'Hello '.
string2 := 'World!'.
complete := string1, string2.
```

Note that in Smalltalk, comma is no syntax but just another message.

Comment: Thanks :) you helped me a lot!

Comment: @nisanarz also note that `#,` is actually collection concatenation, so you can use it to join strings, arrays, sets, ...